# Pinia method with async in Vue3's onMounted hook not executing synchronously - what am I missing?

Tags: async-await, vuejs3, pinia

I used async with a pinia method in the onMounted hook does not execute the code synchronously.
When I try to view {{ store }}, it doesn't display anything. Please let me know what went wrong. Thank you

**page.vue(the page using useCommentStore)**

```
<template>
{{ store }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useStoreStore } from '@/stores/useStoreStore';

const commentStore = useCommentStore();
const { comments, store } = storeToRefs(commentStore);
const {
  getComments,
} = commentStore;

onMounted(async () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  await getComments(route.params.id);
  console.log( store, comments);
});
<script>
```

**useCommentStore.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const useCommentStore = defineStore('comment', () => {
  const comments = ref([]);
  const store = ref({});

  const getComments = (storeId) => {
    axios.get(`/stores/${storeId}?_embed=comments`).then((res) => { comments.value = res.data.comments; store.value = res.data; });
  };

  return {
    comments, getComments,
  };
});
```

Comment: I missed pasting a portion of the code, and now it has been corrected. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: You're not returning `store` from `useCommentStore`. You're only exposing `comments` and `getComments`. As a side note, it's a mistake to store the comments in both `store` and `comments`. You should use a `computed` which extracts `store.comments` instead (which is the equivalent of a `getter` in a classic store).

Comment: Thank you for helping me find this silly mistake. I had been assuming it was an issue with async. I'm curious why computed is used instead of storeToRefs. I would like the comments and store in the page to be able to modify the values within the store as well.

Comment: I never said use `computed` instead of `storeToRefs`. You ***need*** `storeToRefs` to extract any reactive property from the store. You chose the Composition API syntax for the store, instead of the classical syntax (e.g: `state: () => ({}), actions: {}, getters: {}`). In the  Composition store definition, getters are written as computed. But you still need `storeToRefs` in components to turn them into `ref`s.

Comment: You can compare the two store syntaxes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/y8p9s7zb/). I personally prefer the second one, because having to use `foo.value` in some places and `foo` in others makes the code more brittle and slows the development process down. Whereas with classic store syntax you always use `foo`. Just like with `reactive`, you don't need to worry about `.value`. Not having `.value` anywhere adds the benefit of being able to refactor with ease.

Comment: Thing is Composition API makes sense in components, where you want to group separate concerns into separate compostables. but not so much in stores, which are supposed to be specialised anyway (only have one concern). So keeping the classic grouping (`state`, `actions` and `getters`) makes more sense in a store, because the store ***is** the composable*. When you feel the need to group stuff in a store, you should consider adding a separate store, for the new concern.

Comment: I've got it! Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I'll give the option store a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite `getComments`:

```
const getComments = async (storeId) => {
    const result = await axiox.get(`/stores/${storeId}?_embed=comments`);
    comments.value = result.data.comments;
    store.value = result.data;
};
```